# Convergence of a sequence defined by a piecewise recurrence relation.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Test for convergence of the sequence $\langle u_n\rangle,$ where $u_1=7$ and
> $u_n=\begin{cases}5u_{n-1}+1,&\text{ if }u_{n-1}\text{ is odd}\\\\ \frac{u_{n-1}}2,&\text{ if }u_{n-1}\text{ is even}\end{cases}$       for all natural numbers $n\ge2.$

This is a piecewise defined sequence. If it was defined by a single case then I could have tried to express $u_n$ in terms of the base value $u_1$ and then I would apply the limit test. But since there are two cases so it has become difficult for me to draw a conclusion. How to approach this problem? Please give me some hints. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that all the terms of the sequence are integers. (How?)
Thus, if the sequence were to converge, it would have to be constant eventually. (Why?)
However, solving $u_{n+1} = u_n$ shows that this is not possible. (Take two separate cases according to $u_n$ being even or odd.)

Thus, the sequence diverges.

Comment: I got your first two points. But what did you want to mean by solving $u_{n+1}=u_n\,?$ According to me, from the given recurrence relation and the base value $u_1=7,$ it's obvious that the sequence is not a constant sequence and hence it diverges. Thank you.

Comment: "it's obvious that the sequence is not a constant sequence and hence it diverges" - that is not correct to say. A nonconstant sequence of integers may converge since it may become constant *after* a point. This is why I wrote "constant eventually". Thus, what you need to show that it is *never* the case that $u_{n+1} = u_n$. This is what I meant in my last point.

Comment: Oh ok got it. Thanks..

Comment: Okay, great; consider accepting it as an answer then.

Comment: Done! I forgot about it.